# XSLT Date function

Tags: xml, xslt

I have searched google and Here for an answer.
I am trying to use a date formatting function.
I am new to XML but I like to research prior to asking. 
This is for a MS project file that was exported to xml
Here is the function:

```
<xsl:variable name="mdate"><xsl:value-of select="Start"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="format-date($mdate, "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]")"/>
```

My xslt sheet has the proper header info and works untill I try this.
the date comes out like this: 2017-05-31T17:00:00  and I want to drop the time info off and format it to be like this: 05-31-2017

The display after inserting this format-date function causes the form to break and I get a display of the entire file with no spaces in it.

I am using IE11 for the browser. 
If anyone has any info on how to make this work it would speed up my progress.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your description. Are you using a browser to perform your XSL transformation? If so, you are limited to XSLT 1.0 - and `format-date()` is only available in XSLT 2.0. The other thing is you say you want a MM-DD-YYYY result, but your code specifies YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a ISO-8601 dateTime to a date in MM-DD-YYYY format using XSLT 1.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($mdate, 6, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($mdate, 9, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($mdate, 1, 4)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this worked for separating the date from the time. I would like to have the date read "MM/DD/YYYY" instead.  I need to know how to locate the XSLT 1.0 reference so I know what will work. There are a lot of 2.0 info out there and it makes things much more difficult.

Comment: @user3490906 The code above is for XSLT 1.0. I am not sure what you mean by "*have the date read "MM/DD/YYYY" instead*". Is MM/DD/YYYY the input or the output? In any case, it should be pretty trivial to adapt the above principle to any input and/or output: It's a simple string manipulation (XSLT 1.0 does not have a date type).

Comment: I have been doing more reading and just figured out that I looked at what you posted incorrectly. I reapplied and it works perfectly. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XSLT 2.0 date formatting functions client-side, consider using Saxon-JS. The XSLT processors available natively from the browser vendors have been moribund for about 15 years.

A couple of other little things to help you on your XSLT learning curve:

(a) Your variable declaration would be better written `<xsl:variable name="mdate" select="Start"/>` - binding a variable to an element (or sequence of elements) is a much simpler operation than creating a new node tree (or result tree fragment) and copying the data from the source document.

(b) If you do decide to use an XSLT 2.0/3.0 processor, the input to `format-date()` must be an `xs:date`, whereas your value looks like an `xs:dateTime`.

I know it's old-fashioned but learning the concepts of a new language through google is really hard work; when you're starting it's very hard to distinguish quality information from dross, and when you find quality information you may not understand it because it assumes more knowledge than you have at this stage of the learning curve. In my view, since you say you like to research things, there's really no substitute for a good book.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do plan on locating a good book for this. However how does one get the XSLT 2.0/3.0 processor set up? I have been researching the W3 site and sifting through MS's site on the subject.

Comment: I did add this to the top of my XSLT sheet: "<xsl:stylesheet 
 version="1.0" 
exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt fn"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
xmlns:fn="https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/">"

Comment: Information about Saxon-JS, which is the only complete implementation of XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 on the browser platform, is at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml